# Allow scrolling past end of page

Tags: browser, scrolling

Is there any option in a webbrowser (IE, Firefox or Chrome) to allow scrolling up to one screenful past the end pf the page? When reading a long page of text and pressing PAGE-DOWN to scroll to the next page, the text at the bottom of the browser window is scrolled to the top of the window (with an approximate overlap of two lines). When scrolling to the last half- or quarter-screen, the bottom is scrolled to somewhere in the middle of the browser window (based on how long the remainder of the document is), forcing me to search for my place.

A plugin or addon that would allow toggling this behavior would be even better.

Something like the ScrollPastEOF plugin for Notepad++, but for web browsers.

Comment: The design of the page regulates this;  if the designer ended the page at the last line of text or only an extra line or two, the last line will NOT be in the middle of the browser window, it will be at the bottom.  The bottom of the page -- as designed -- is the bottom of the page, blank lines or fill space, or not.

Comment: @Debra I am looking for a plugin that will artificially extend the page by the viewport height, allowing the behavior I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a chrome extension just for you, it's a pretty rough fix but it will get the job done without doing anything else. Check it out:
https://github.com/LudwikJaniuk/MorePageSpace/releases/

**Note to you:**
This might not work on super-interactive websites that have parallax effects and what-not. Try and you'll see.

**Note to web developers who read the source code:**
Yes, I know there are better ways to do this than appending a few dozen `<br/>` to the page's HTML.

**Note to you if you happen to be a web developer or at least know simple HTML:**
What the extension basically does is it appends a lot of `<br/>` tags at the end of the page body when you click its button. I added a lot of them since my screen is pretty big but if you decide you still want more, you can always click it twice. Or thrice... ;)

Also, you sure could have went in and manipulated the source of the website yourself. But isn't pressing a button much easier?

Comment: This seems like it will do for my purpose. But why not set the body's height to the current height + the viewport height?

Comment: As I said, this is by far not the best nor the only way to do it... However, I'm not sure setting the body height would have worked, what if the browser still positioned the text at the end of the body? Who knows, never tested that. Anyways, if this helped you, please accept my answer wit hthe checkmark :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is the CSS code I use for this, the version that caused me less problems on less sites. See Stylish addon or the corresponding thing for your browser in order to install it. The '700px' is my page view area minus some small amount in order to make last lines visible at the end of scroll.

```
html {
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 700px !important;
}
```

For example, in Firefox browser, click 'Write blank style' in Stylish menu, then enter the following code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://), url-prefix(https://), url-prefix(ftp://), url-prefix(file://) {
    html {
        height: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 700px !important;
    }
}
```

I should add that I tested it on Firefox only, although it should work on any browser.

Comment: Instead of 700px, you can use "100vh" or perhaps "90vh" ("vh" means view port height) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/420867).